# Mysql query when column has content

Tags: php, mysql

How do I select an array of all mysql rows of which in addition to a first condition, one of the columns has content in it. (column2 below)

Is this how I should do it?

```
mysql_query("  SELECT * FROM table 
               WHERE (column1 != '$var1') AND (column2 != "")  ");
```

Thanks!

Comment: it's a number retreived earlier from a post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove unnecessary parentheses. they concerns Some of the optimizations performed by MySQL.

It should be like below :

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 != '".$var1."' AND column2 != ''");
```

Comment: Plz check your query, you forget to close the `mysql_query()`

Comment: ok I deleted them, but this is otherwise the same right? I don't want to miss anything. Thank you!